# Laravel 5 - Show only if 'tip_date' column is equal to todays date

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 install and I have a database of tips with various columns...one column being the date that the tip is relevant for.

Therefore I only want to show the rows of the table that date is equal to todays date.

I have managed to get it so I can run a foreach to cycle through every tip but need a specific one just to show the tips that match todays date

Any would be great :)

Here is my code

---

TipsController

```
public function index() {
        $tips = Tips::whereDate('tip_date','=', strftime("%y-%m-%d", strtotime(\Carbon\Carbon::now())))->get();
        return view ('tips.index', compact ('tips'));
    }
```

Tips (Model)

```
protected $fillable = [

        'tip_date',
        'home_team',
        'away_team',
        'league',
        'tip',
        'odds',
        'score',
        'result'

    ];

    protected $dates = ['tip_date'];
```

Index.Blade.PHP (View)

```
<div class="align-center">

                                 <h1><?php echo date("dS F Y");?></h1>


                                 @foreach($tips as $tip)
                                     @if (date("Y-m-d",strtotime($tip['tip_date'])) == date("Y-m-d"))

                                 <h3>{{ $tip->league }}</h3>
                                 <h2>{{ $tip->home_team }} V {{ $tip->away_team }}</h2>
                                 <h3><b>{{ $tip->tip }}</b> @ {{ $tip->odds }}</h3>
                                 @endif
                                 @endforeach


                    </div>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Match</th>
                          <th>Tip</th>
                          <th>Odds</th>
                          <th>Score</th>
                          <th>Result</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>


<?php $tipcount=0; ?>
@foreach($tips as $tip)
    @if (date("Y-m-d",strtotime($tip['tip_date'])) < date("Y-m-d"))
 <tr>
                              <th scope="row">{{ $tip->tip_date }}</th>
                              <td>{{ $tip->home_team }} V {{ $tip->away_team }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $tip->tip }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $tip->odds }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $tip->score }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $tip->result }}</td>
                            </tr>    @endif


    <?php
    $tipcount++;
    if($tipcount===30){break;};
    ?>


@endforeach
```

Comment: Would it perhaps be an option to use the database to return only the rows for today? or are you needing to return all records and then parse them for today's tips?

Comment: It would be better if you get all the tips for today rather than getting all the tips and then filtering through a loop.

Comment: I need to get todays tip to show at the top of the page and then in a table the last 30 tips excluding todays below it, both on the same page/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jamal said...
But on the view / foreach side you could try:

```
@foreach($tips as $tip)
    @if (date("Y-m-d",strtotime($tip['tip_date'])) == date("Y-m-d"))
        {{$tip->name}}
    @endif
@endforeach

<?php $tipcount=0; ?>
@foreach($tips as $tip)
    @if (date("Y-m-d",strtotime($tip['tip_date'])) < date("Y-m-d"))
        {{$tip->name}}
    @endif


    <?php 
    $tipcount++; 
    if($tipcount===30){break;}; 
    ?>  
@endforeach
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly, now I need to create a table in the same view below that displaying the 30 previous tips excluding todays date...any ideas?

Comment: See my edited answer to include option for extra table. It's a bit of a hack but should do the job!

Comment: Couldn't get the second part to work it wont show the results in the table :(

Comment: Edit your question to post the relevant code and we can take a look.

Comment: The code looks fine - I have tested it out on my side and all is fine so it possibly is data related. Display the recordset count somewhere so you can be sure there are actual records being passed through from the controller. Change the parameters for the second foreach (like if 1==1) to check the code is actually getting into that loop.

Comment: Oh wait - check the $tips = Tips::whereDate('tip_date','=', strftime("%y-%m-%d", strtotime(\Carbon\Carbon::now())))->get() - you seem to be only passing through today's records...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84140/discussion-between-phil-nind-and-mhluzi-bhaka).

Answer (score 1):

You can get today's tips as:

```
$tips = Tip::whereDate('tip_date','=', strftime("%y-%m-%d", strtotime(\Carbon\Carbon::now())))->get();
```

And then run the foreach loop on the available tips for the current date.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform this check in many views in your code you can implement a `isToday()` method in your `Tip` model.

In your Model

```
public function isToday()
{
    return $this->date == date('Y-m-d');
}
```

Supposing `$tips` is already the collection correctly retrieved from wherever you have it.

In your blade view

```
@foreach($tips as $tip)
    @if($tip->isToday())
       /* whatever you want to display */
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Of course this is an example and you may wish to adjust the date checking according to your naming conventions and fields format, for example using Carbon.

> **Advice** if your tips collection is actually a relationship of another model then your for might change a bit, depending on how you called the relationship and how are you retrieving them.

Comment: After trying this one I get the following error.... 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::isToday()'

Comment: Where are you using it? You are calling it as static, thats not the way. I will add some more code.

Comment: Are your tips part (relationship) of another model?